generateMetadata function is not fetching data
I am following a new Next.js tutorial on Udemy by Jonas Schemdtmann and we are building a website for a luxurious boutique hotel called The Wild Oasis. There is a part where the cabin details will be fetched in a dynamic page and there is also a generateMetadata function that will fetch the same data and display the name of the cabin as a title. But, the cabin data is being fetched correctly inside the page but when I added the generateMetadata, the cabin data in the page will be null. If I comment out the generateMetadata funtion, the getCabinWithId function fetch the cabin data correctly. I think Next.js waits for the data fetching inside the generateMetadata to complete before streaming the UI to the client and for some reason the cabin data is null inside the generateMetadata function. Here is the dynamic page responsible for fetching the cabin data and displaying it:
type props = {
  params: { cabinId: number };
};

export async function generateMetadata({ params }: props): Promise<Metadata> {
  const { cabinId } = params;
  const cabin = await getCabinWithId(cabinId);

  return { title: `Cabin ${cabin?.name}` };
}

export default async function Page({ params }: props) {
  const { cabinId } = params;

  const cabin = await getCabinWithId(cabinId);
  console.log(cabin);

  return (
    <div className='max-w-6xl mx-auto mt-8'>
      <div className='grid grid-cols-[3fr_4fr] gap-20 border border-primary-800 py-3 px-10 mb-24'>
        <div className='relative scale-[1.15] -translate-x-3'>
          <Image
            src={cabin?.image as string}
            fill
            alt={`Cabin ${cabin?.name}`}
            className=' object-cover'
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <h3 className='text-accent-100 font-black text-7xl mb-5 translate-x-[-254px] bg-primary-950 p-6 pb-1 w-[150%]'>
            Cabin {cabin?.name}
          </h3>

          <p className='text-lg text-primary-300 mb-10'>{cabin?.description}</p>

          <ul className='flex flex-col gap-4 mb-7'>
            <li className='flex gap-3 items-center'>
              <UsersIcon className='h-5 w-5 text-primary-600' />
              <span className='text-lg'>
                For up to{' '}
                <span className='font-bold'>{cabin?.maxCapacity}</span> guests
              </span>
            </li>
            <li className='flex gap-3 items-center'>
              <MapPinIcon className='h-5 w-5 text-primary-600' />
              <span className='text-lg'>
                Located in the heart of the{' '}
                <span className='font-bold'>Dolomites</span> (Italy)
              </span>
            </li>
            <li className='flex gap-3 items-center'>
              <EyeIcon className='h-5 w-5 text-primary-600' />
              <span className='text-lg'>
                Privacy <span className='font-bold'>100%</span> guaranteed
              </span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h2 className='text-5xl font-semibold text-center'>
          Reserve today. Pay on arrival.
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

Here is the getCabinWithId function:
export async function getCabinWithId(cabinId: number) {
  try {
    const cabin = await prisma.cabins.findUnique({ where: { id: cabinId } });

    return cabin;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return null;
  }
}

I checked the Next.js doc but didn't find anything. I comment out the generateMetadata function for now and the page is inherited the root metadata and everything is working fine. But, it is kind of weird seeing "Welcomd to the wild oasis" instead of the name of the cabin as a page title
